# Фото переворачивается при загрузке через Codeigniter (exif)

Tags: php, codeigniter

Загружаю фото через PHP. При загрузке фото переворачивается. Как поменять Ориентацию изображения?

Вывожу через exif

```
$path=FCPATH.'images/tech/'.$upldata['orig_name'];
$exif = exif_read_data($path);
print_r($exif);
```

Показывает [Orientation] => 1, а нужно [Orientation] => 6. Что делать?

UPD

Загружаю так

```
$_FILES['images[]']['name']     = $_FILES['photo']['name'][$key];
$_FILES['images[]']['type']     = $_FILES['photo']['type'][$key];
$_FILES['images[]']['tmp_name']= $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'][$key];
$_FILES['images[]']['error']= $_FILES['photo']['error'][$key];
$_FILES['images[]']['size']= $_FILES['photo']['size'][$key];
$fn= $this->getRandomString();
$config['file_name']=$fn;
$this->upload->initialize($config);
$upldata=$this->upload->data();
```

Comment: Как вы его загружаете-то?

Comment: @andreymal обновил вопрос

Comment: Что такое `$this->upload`?

Comment: @andreymal это библиотека от codeignither. с помощью нету гружу